# Git extra hook, pre-upload

Tags: ruby, git, github, githooks

I'm a university student. Currently, I’m doing my Final Year Project that requires a hook that executes automatically on the server side of the repository, before the objects been pulled to the client side, and after the objects have been pushed to the server side, which is "post-receive" hook.

I have done lots of research regard on the hook and I came to know grack and rjgit_grack. Links will be attached below.

Grack : https://github.com/grackorg/grack
Rjgit_grack : https://github.com/grackorg/rjgit_grack

Grack and rjgit_grack is a gem from https://rubygems.org/. Grack project aims to replace the builtin git-http-backend CGI handler distributed with C Git with a Rack application and rjgit_grack is an alternative adapter of grack that support extra hooks for git that have the hook that I needed for my project, "preUpload" hook that is executed immediately before an upload-operation is performed, i.e. before data is sent to the client. But I was unable to get it to work for my project due to various reasons.

Why Git doesn't have a hook that executed immediately before the data is sent to the client? Any advice on getting this hook or any similar function of the hook?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind Git hooks is that they do at least one of two things: change the state of the repository or the current operation, or optionally block a behavior from occurring.

A hook that executes before objects are pushed wouldn't be able to do either one of these: it has no data about how to change the repository, since it doesn't have any objects, and without any data about what's going on, there's no way that it can usefully determine whether to block a push.

For your project, it might be useful to wrap the git HTTP backend script with a wrapper that executes before the push service starts, or one that looks for the flush pkt-line delimiter (0000) by intercepting the data. You could also patch Git to have the hook you need for your project at the appropriate location.